# Call NavigationService from Silverlight UserControl that contains Navigation Frame

Tags: silverlight, navigationservice

I have a UserControl that contains a Frame with a UriMapper. This is also my RootVisual, so it is what is loaded when the application is loaded. This is my (simplified) XAML:

```
<UserControl>
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/Page1">
        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame>

<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Page1Link" NavigateUri="/Page1" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Page1"/>
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Page2Link" NavigateUri="/Page2" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Page2"/>
</UserControl>
```

This all works great, but now I want to add a back-button. When the user clicks the button, I want to call

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

I can call the NavigationService from the pages (Page1 and Page2), but how can I call the NavigationService from this 'parent' UserControl? Is it possible? In this UserControl, the NavigationService is always null.

I would either want to access the NavigationService from the pages shown in the Frame, or pass the button click event to these pages.

I don't want to have to put a button in each Page and handle the navigation there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(YOUR_URI);
```

and

```
ContentFrame.GoBack();
```

in your parent UserControl that contains the navigation frame with x:Name="ContentFrame".